# React Native dependency error

Tags: node.js, mobile, npm, react-native, npm-install

I'm brand new to React Native, I wanted to install an UI toolkit to simplify my UI design process so I went ahead and installed @shoutem/ui. After the installation I ran my application and I got a dependency error:

[image]

I went ahead and installed string_decoder (npm install --save string_decoder) so it now shows as a module under my node_modules folder but I still get the same error.

I tried to troubleshoot this by following the steps the error message shows, still getting it. Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it' from packager cache. start packager with this command:

```
npm start --reset-cache
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work, thanks for your reply tho.

Answer (score 0):

React Native v40 had some [breaking changes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.40.0) which caused Shoutem UI toolkit not to work. It will be solved in the following days. In the meantime, [here](https://github.com/shoutem/ui/issues/134#issuecomment-273977589) is a temporary solution.

Comment: Interesting, I'm going to give it a try and also I'll be waiting for that update. Thanks for your reply.